# Class hierarchy terms, ancestor- vs. parent-class

Tags: oop

Im trying to understand the various definitions, other students do not quite agree with me.

My definitions, please correct them if wrong:

Base class is the top most class in the hierarchy.

Super and Ancestor class, any class higher up in the hierarchy (including the base class)

Parent class, the next class up in the hierarchy.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about your super definition. I'd consider Super and Parent the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. **Parent Classes** are the direct superclasses (up to one level in the hierarchy) of your class. Depending on your programming language, a class can have multiple parents.

While an ancestor class, is any superclass of your class (a parent class, a parent of a parent class and so on).

Comment: [1 NSButton -> 2 NSControl -> 3 NSView -> 4 NSResponder -> 5 NSObject]
1 is the child of 2,   
2 is the parent of 1,   
2 3 4 5 are the ancestors of 1,   
3 4 5 are NOT the parents of 1.  

What would the base class(es) be?

Comment: The Base class in this case is 5. 5 Does not extend other classes.

Comment: Thank you. I was skeptical about my own class's definition that ancestors do not include the parent class, but only parents of the parent class.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_class#Subclasses_and_superclasses) a base class is any class from which another class inherits one or more properties or methods. If you accept this definition, it means that super, ancestor, parent and base class are all synonymous with each other in terms of describing the relationship of a class with a particular sub-class.